# KeyError: 337 when training a hugging face model using pytorch

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, text-classification, huggingface-transformers

I am training a simple binary classification model using `Hugging face models` using `pytorch.`

Bert PyTorch HuggingFace.

Here is the code:

```
import transformers
from transformers import TFAutoModel, AutoTokenizer
from tokenizers import Tokenizer, models, pre_tokenizers, decoders, processors
from transformers import AutoTokenizer

 
from transformers import AdamW
from transformers import get_linear_schedule_with_warmup
from transformers import BertTokenizerFast as BertTokenizer, BertModel, AdamW, get_linear_schedule_with_warmup,BertConfig
```

I am reading a text-data and classifying it as toxic or non-toxic. I have downloaded and saved model in path.

```
BERT_MODEL_NAME = '/home/pch/conv-bert-base'
MODEL_PATHS = {'conv-bert-base': '/home/pch/conv-bert-base/'}
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained(BERT_MODEL_NAME)

TRANSFORMERS = {"conv-bert-base": (BertModel, BertTokenizer, "conv-bert-base")}


class SEDataset(Dataset):
    """
    Sexually Explicit dataset for the hate speech.
    """
    def __init__(self, df,tokenizer: BertTokenizer, max_token_len: int = 512):
        """
        Constructor
        
        Arguments:
            df {pandas dataframe} -- Dataframe where the data is. 
        """
            
        super().__init__()
        self.df = df 
        self.tokenizer = tokenizer
        self.max_token_len = max_token_len
        

        try:
            self.y = df['toxic'].values
        except KeyError: # test data
            self.y = np.zeros(len(df))

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.df)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        
        data_row = self.df[idx]

        text_data = data_row['text']
        
        encoding = tokenizer.encode_plus(
                  text_data,
                  add_special_tokens=True,
                  max_length=512,
                  return_token_type_ids=False,
                  padding="max_length",
                  return_attention_mask=True,
                  return_tensors='pt',)
        
        self.word_ids = encoding["input_ids"]
        self.attention_mask=encoding["attention_mask"]
        
        return self.word_ids[idx], torch.tensor(self.y[idx]), self.attention_mask[idx]



class Transformer(nn.Module):
    
    def __init__(self, model, num_classes=1):
        """
        Constructor
        
        Arguments:
            model {string} -- Transformer to build the model on. Expects "conv-bert-base".
            num_classes {int} -- Number of classes (default: {1})
        """
        super().__init__()
        self.name = model

        model_class, tokenizer_class, pretrained_weights = TRANSFORMERS[model]

        bert_config = BertConfig.from_json_file(MODEL_PATHS[model] + 'config.json')
        bert_config.output_hidden_states = True
        
        self.transformer = BertModel(bert_config)

        self.nb_features = self.transformer.pooler.dense.out_features

        self.pooler = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(self.nb_features, self.nb_features), 
            nn.Tanh(),
        )

        self.logit = nn.Linear(self.nb_features, num_classes)

    def forward(self, tokens):
        """
        Usual torch forward function
        
        Arguments:
            tokens {torch tensor} -- Sentence tokens
        
        Returns:
            torch tensor -- Class logits
        """
        _, _, hidden_states = self.transformer(
            tokens, attention_mask=(tokens > 0).long()
        )

        hidden_states = hidden_states[-1][:, 0] # Use the representation of the first token of the last layer

        ft = self.pooler(hidden_states)

        return self.logit(ft)



def fit(model, train_dataset, val_dataset, epochs=1, batch_size=32, warmup_prop=0, lr=5e-5):
    
    device = torch.device('cuda')
    model.to(device)
    
    train_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)
    val_loader = DataLoader(val_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False)

    optimizer = AdamW(model.parameters(), lr=lr)
    
    num_warmup_steps = int(warmup_prop * epochs * len(train_loader))
    num_training_steps = epochs * len(train_loader)
    
    scheduler = get_linear_schedule_with_warmup(optimizer, num_warmup_steps, num_training_steps)

    loss_fct = nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss(reduction='mean').to(device)
    
    for epoch in range(epochs):
        model.train()
        start_time = time.time()
        
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        avg_loss = 0
        
        for step, (x, y_batch) in tqdm(enumerate(train_loader), total=len(train_loader)): 
            y_pred = model(x.to(device))
            
            loss = loss_fct(y_pred.view(-1).float(), y_batch.float().to(device))
            loss.backward()
            avg_loss += loss.item() / len(train_loader)

            xm.optimizer_step(optimizer, barrier=True)
            scheduler.step()
            model.zero_grad()
            optimizer.zero_grad()
                
        model.eval()
        preds = []
        truths = []
        avg_val_loss = 0.

        with torch.no_grad():
            for x, y_batch in val_loader:                
                y_pred = model(x.to(device))
                loss = loss_fct(y_pred.detach().view(-1).float(), y_batch.float().to(device))
                avg_val_loss += loss.item() / len(val_loader)
                
                probs = torch.sigmoid(y_pred).detach().cpu().numpy()
                preds += list(probs.flatten())
                truths += list(y_batch.numpy().flatten())
            score = roc_auc_score(truths, preds)
            
        
        dt = time.time() - start_time
        lr = scheduler.get_last_lr()[0]
        print(f'Epoch {epoch + 1}/{epochs} \t lr={lr:.1e} \t t={dt:.0f}s \t loss={avg_loss:.4f} \t val_loss={avg_val_loss:.4f} \t val_auc={score:.4f}')


model = Transformer("conv-bert-base")
epochs = 1 # 1 epoch seems to be enough
batch_size = 32
warmup_prop = 0.1
lr = 2e-5  # Important parameter to tweak

train_dataset = SEDataset(df3,tokenizer)
val_dataset = SEDataset(val_data,tokenizer)

fit(model, train_dataset, val_dataset, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, warmup_prop=warmup_prop, lr=lr)
```

I have attached all the codes above.

**Error:**

**0%|          | 0/29 [00:00<?, ?it/s]

KeyError: 337**

Answer (score 2):

For me this error was happening when passing a Pandas DataFrame with values missing in the index i.e 0, 1, 2, 4. Changing the index to 0, 1, 2, 3 fixed the problem.